# How to set initial capactiy of a nested Lists?

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to set initial capacity of a nested `ArrayList` to some value (say 10), but when I tried to access the internal list to add some element it's giving me `ArrayOutOfBoundException`. Please suggest some good solution !!!

Below is the code snippet

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> bucket = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    System.out.println(bucket.get(5).add(5));       

    System.out.println(bucket);
}
```

Comment: Setting the initial capacity won't change anything. You can't access an element of the list if the index is invalid, whatever the capacity is. If you want to access element at index 5, then the **size** of the list must be at least 6

Comment: Initial capacity is not the actual size, just a limit on how much space to allocate.

Comment: @JBNizet Is there any way out ???

Comment: `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> bucket = Stream.generate(ArrayList<Integer>::new) .limit(size).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code :

```
 public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> bucket = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();      

        //initial capacity of the nested arraylist to 5.  
        System.out.println(bucket.add(new ArrayList<>(5)));
        ArrayList<Integer> element = new ArrayList<>();
        element.add(5);
        bucket.add(0, element);
        System.out.println(bucket);
    }

}
```

Output :

```
true
[[5], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(bucket.get(5).add(5));
```

You need to understand this line of code, you are trying to access the 5th Element from the Array List "bucket", but have you added any elements in the bucket `ArrayList` (in you case the element being another Array List)

Unless you add your elements, you cannot access them, as they do not exist, hence you see the `ArrayOutOfBoundException` while you are trying to access 5th element at `bucket.get(5)`

you might want to go through the javadoc of ArrayList
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Is there any way using which i may Initialize "bucket" variable with "N" empty Arraylist, like the one i tried in this case....

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Java 8, you can generate a list of empty lists using `Stream.generate`.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class ListOfLists {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> bucket = listOfList(10);
        bucket.get(5).add(5);
        System.out.println(bucket);
    }

    public static <T> List<List<T>> listOfList(int size) {
        return Stream.generate(ArrayList<T>::new).limit(size).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

#### Output

> ```
> [[], [], [], [], [], [5], [], [], [], []]
> ```